# Как подставить значение?

Tags: php, sql, ооп, pdo

Как получить данные из формы для подстановки в запрос?
Здравствуйте.

Есть форма:

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
          <input type="search" name="q" placeholder="<?= $_GET['q'] ?? 'Запрос' ?>" >
          <input type="submit" value="">
        </div>
      </form>
```

В модели, которая наследуется от абстрактного класса:

```
public static function search(array $searchData){
      if (empty($searchData['q'])) {
          throw new InvalidArgumentException('Запрос');
        }
    }
```

Т.е. здесь мы получаем значение так: *$searchData['q']*

Контроллер:

```
public function search(){
      try{
          $user = Article::search($_GET);
      }catch (InvalidArgumentException $e) {
          $this->view->renderHtml('search/search.php', ['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
          return;
    }
    $articles = Article::searchArticles('q', $searchData['q']);
    $this->view->renderHtml('search/search.php', ['articles' => $articles]
  );
  }
```

И теперь абстрактный класс, который наследует модель:

```
public static function searchArticles(string $value): array{
        $db = Db::getInstance();
        return $db->query('SELECT * FROM `' . static::getTableName() . '` WHERE `name` LIKE :value', [':value' => $value], static::class);
    }
```

Я не понимаю, как мне подставить значение поля

```
<input type="search" name="q" placeholder="<?= $_GET['q'] ?? 'Запрос' ?>" >
```

Т.е. если я сделаю например

```
return $db->query('SELECT * FROM `' . static::getTableName() . '` WHERE `name` LIKE \'%test%\' ', [':value' => $value], static::class);
```

все будет прекрасно, но как мне сделать так, чтобы это значение подставлялось автоматически из get запроса?

Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: попробуйте в поиск свой ввести `"><script>alert('hello world);</script>` для интереса

Comment: это pdo вообще-то, здесь такое не прокатит)

Comment: а я и не про pdo, это не sql инъекция

Comment: спешу расстроить, ничего не происходит ;)

Comment: кавычки потому что не хватает в алерте. у вас в html-форме `_GET['q']` подставляется без всякого экранирования

Comment: возможно у вас как раз с этим проблема, но когда вы ее решите, вот и получите этот косяк

Comment: мне нужно как-то в запрос к бд отправить, я не знаю как, целый день мучаюсь